# homebrew doesn't recognize --devel flag

Tags: homebrew

I am trying to install octave following [these](http://www.schoeps.org/home/2018/01/how-to-compile-gnu-octave-with-openblas-on-macos/) instructions.

```
brew tap dpo/openblas
brew tap-pin dpo/openblas
brew install dpo/openblas/octave --HEAD --with-qt --with-java
```

The last line tells me

```
==> Installing octave from dpo/openblas
Error: Option '--with-qt' requires '--DEVEL'.
```

So I try

```
brew install --devel dpo/openblas/octave --HEAD --with-qt --with-java
brew install --DEVEL dpo/openblas/octave --HEAD --with-qt --with-java
```

And get the same error messages. How can I install with '--DEVEL'?

Comment: Remove the `--HEAD` option, it conflicts with `--devel`

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking for the solution, it is described [here](https://github.com/dpo/homebrew-openblas/issues/51).

```
brew install dpo/openblas/octave --with-qt --devel
```

`--with-java` gives a warning that legacy JDK6 is required, but there is apparently a fix for that [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/4643) if you want to install it.